# How to process and check unique IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, transactions, rows, indexof

I have a multiple transacation lines, and I would like to see if I could process each one in a for loop, or at least store them in an array such that I could lookup and check to see if the transaction id has been referenced.

My data looks like:

```
PersonID | TranID | LineID | Info
123      |  1     | 0      | Apples
123      |  1     | 1      | Oranges
145      |  2     | 0      | Bananas
145      |  2     | 1      | Popcorn
145      |  2     | 2      | Mushrooms
```

And what I would like to uniquely parse:

```
123
#1
Apples
Oranges

~~

145
#2
Bananas
Popcorn
Mushrooms
```

I was thinking of:

```
var transaction = new Array();

for (var i = 0; datarows != null && i <= datarows.length; i++){

   if datarows[i].tranID is not in transaction{

   write the rows
   transaction.push(datarows[i].tranID)

   } else {
   return;
 }
}
```

The problem is .. I don't actually store the Line ID, so I can't process each individual line. Help!

Comment: Are you using jQuery by any chance?

Comment: I could, but it's currently only simple javascript.

Comment: Your coding is ok, but the approach to processing is off -- your algorithm is wrong. The value that you're storing in the `transaction` array should be an object (`{}`) containing values for the `personId` and `transactionId`, and an array of `info` strings. On each pass through datarows check if you have a matching record in your `transaction` array (by looping through it and finding a match on the `transactionId`) -- if you haven't then you should create the record and push it to the array, but if you have then you should retrieve the record and add the new info string to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. Here is what you need to do (Assuming you're using jQuery - I usually find it easier) -

```js
var dataArray = [
  {personId: 123, tranId: 1, lineId: 0, info: 'Apples'},
  {personId:123, tranId:1, lineId:1, info:'Oranges'},
  {personId:145, tranId:2, lineId:0, info:'Bananas'},
  {personId:145, tranId:2, lineId:1, info:'Popcorn'},
  {personId:145, tranId:2, lineId:2, info:'Mushrooms'}
];

//Don't bother about this
$.each(dataArray, function(colIndex, item){ 
  
  var row = $('<tr/>'); 
  
  $.each(item, function(rowIndex, it){       
    row.append($('<td/>').text(it));    
  });
    
  $('#data tbody').append(row);
});

// Have an array for filtered objects
var filteredArray = [];

// Iterate through data array
$.each(dataArray, function(index, item){
  
  if(filteredArray.length == 0)
    filteredArray.push(item);
  
  // a flag to tell you if the data exists in the filtered array or not
  var addItem = true;
  
  // Check if the data exists in the filtered array
  var filteredItem = $.grep(filteredArray, function(filItem, filIndex, filAll){
    
    // Here is where you check whatever conditions you want
    if(filItem.personId == item.personId && filItem.tranId == item.tranId) {
     addItem = false;
      return false;
    }      
  });
  
  // Add the data
  if(addItem)
    filteredArray.push(item);
});


//Don't bother about this
$.each(filteredArray, function(colIndex, item){ 
  
  var row = $('<tr/>'); 
  
  $.each(item, function(rowIndex, it){       
    row.append($('<td/>').text(it));    
  });
    
  $('#filteredData tbody').append(row);
});
```

```css
#data{
  border: grey 1px solid;
}

#filteredData{
  border: grey 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
  <thead>
  <th>PersonID</th>
  <th>TranID</th>
  <th>LineID</th>
  <th>Info</th>  
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<br/><br/>

<table id="filteredData">
   <thead>
  <th>PersonID</th>
  <th>TranID</th>
  <th>LineID</th>
  <th>Info</th>  
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Also, here is the CodePen - http://codepen.io/aswinramakrish/pen/YPQZBj